# Issue on using composite primary key as a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have made a composite key as a primary key for table Airlines.
And I want to use that primary key as a foreign key for table Flights.
With that what I want is to have Flights that

1. that either are not related to Airlines,
2. or if they are, they need to have both columns of the composite key.

Below are tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Airlines (
  name char(32),
  country char(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (name, country)
);

CREATE TABLE Flights_operate (
  num integer PRIMARY KEY,
  dept timestamp,
  arr timestamp,
  name_Airlines char(32),
  country_Airlines char(32),
  CONSTRAINT FK
  FOREIGN KEY (name_Airlines, country_Airlines) REFERENCES Airlines (name, country)
);
```

I tried using `CONSTRAINT` but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

I can still insert rows with a `name_Airlines` and without a `country_Airlines` like so:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aTYv.png)

What should I do?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Read the manual re the functionality you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disallow just one of the columns in the foreign key from being null, you can use MATCH FULL (see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)).

```sql
CREATE TABLE Flights_operate (
  num integer PRIMARY KEY,
  dept timestamp,
  arr timestamp,
  name_Airlines char(32),
  country_Airlines char(32),
  CONSTRAINT FK
  FOREIGN KEY (name_Airlines, country_Airlines) 
  REFERENCES Airlines (name, country) MATCH FULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Flights_operate (
  num integer PRIMARY KEY,
  dept timestamp,
  arr timestamp,
  name_Airlines char(32),
  country_Airlines char(32),
  CONSTRAINT FK
  FOREIGN KEY (name_Airlines, country_Airlines) REFERENCES Airlines (name, country),
  CHECK (name_Airlines IS NOT NULL AND country_Airlines IS NOT NULL OR
         name_Airlines IS NULL AND country_Airlines IS NULL
        )
);
```

Some additional notes.

First, do not use `char` as a data type for names.  It pads the strings with spaces, which is generally undesirable.

Second, consider having an identity/serial primary key for all your tables.  This is more efficient than strings -- consider 4 bytes for an integer versus 64 bytes for your composite key.